# how to display the text from text field on the screen by clicking button on React

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and very new to it. how can i display whats inside the textfield on the screen by button click . like when i type "React" on the textfield then press the button it display "React" on the right ? like the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a hook to handle text changes: `const [text, setText] = useState("");`. Then you can create a function to handle the submission of the form and trigger it on submit of the form. This function will prevent the page from reloading using `event.preventDefault()` and then use the hook from above to change the text of an element using the text inside the form (defined as `event.target[0].value`).

Full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setText(event.target[0].value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: We are getting the error: Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **useState** and **useRef** hooks to achieve this. First, you need a reference for your input field and then pass that reference to set the state. Please check this code, it will explain you better.

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";


export default function App() {
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  return (
     <div className="App">
       <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
       <button onClick={() => setInput(inputRef.current.value)}>Button</button>
       <p>{input}</p>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Please vote up if you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom hooks to render the input text into your page ,

```
import React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
export const Body = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("React");
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="search-text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button>Search </button> <h1>{searchText}</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```